# Error when trying to run jupyter notebook: Import error: no module named jupyter_core.command

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

I am running Ubuntu Linux on my laptop, Anaconda 3 with python version 3.6. Jupyter notebook worked fine for me the last time I used it on this computer, but that was 3 months ago. So today I turn it on and try to run jupyter notebook, and I get this error:

```
john@john-Satellite-L55Dt-B:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/john/anaconda3/bin/jupyter", line 7, in <module>
    from jupyter_core.command import main
ImportError: No module named jupyter_core.command
```

I'll admit I'm completely lost and a little rusty with my LINUX, so what do I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Try to export the below path and take jupyter noteboo again.Hope this helps.

```
export PATH= /home/john/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

You can create a conda environment using the below command:

```
conda create -n env_sample -c intel python=3.6
```

To activate the environment use the below command:

```
source activate env_sample
```

env_sample is the environment name

Comment: I got this error:
bash: export: `/home/john/anaconda3/bin:/home/john/anaconda3/bin:/home/john/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin': not a valid identifier

Comment: I also looked at my bashrc, this path is still in there:
export PATH="/home/john/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

Comment: Could you please try the same after creating a conda environment

Comment: How? I'm not able to.

Comment: I tried, I get the error:
john@john-Satellite-L55Dt-B:~/anaconda3$ export PATH= \home\john\anaconda3\bin:$PATH
bash: export: `homejohnanaconda3bin:/home/john/anaconda3/bin:/home/john/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin': not a valid identifier